# EJS - How to display variables/variables not showing up

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs, embedded-javascript

I'll just give the run-down.

Server.js:

```
// load the things we need
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// set the view engine to ejs
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// use res.render to load up an ejs view file

// index page 
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    var tagline = "Any code of your own that you haven't looked at for six or more months might as well have been written by someone else";

    res.render('pages/index', {
        tagline: tagline
    });
});

// about page 
app.get('/about', function(req, res) {
    res.render('pages/about');
});

app.listen(8080);
console.log('8080 is the magic port');
```

And in index.ejs, the bit I need to display is here:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1>This is great</h1>
  <h2><%= tagline %></h2>
  <p>Welcome to templating using EJS</p>
</div>
```

However, when I run these codes together, I get all of the page, par the `<%= tagline %>` part. This is very much an annoyance for me, as it means I currently cannot use EJS variables. Can anyone help?!

Comment: It works for me what output are you getting and you elaborate ?

Comment: Sorry, it was my stupid mistake. I was trying to load about.html, not index.html. That's why it didn't show up on the page.